# What causes strange differences with background URLSession between ios 8.1 and ios 10.2 on simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-simulator, ios10

I am experiencing a strange behaviour debugging my app.

I have a straight forward URLSession with background configuration:

```
        let backgroundSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: (prefix + postfix))
        let backgroundSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: backgroundSessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

        progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)

        var request = URLRequest(url: dlUrl )
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.cachePolicy = NSMutableURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        let task = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: request)

        task.resume()
```

My test ist as follows:

1. start download in app.
2. bring app to background.
3. notify when background download is finished.
4. After click on notification app comes to foreground

When I try this with a simulator under **ios 10.2** the app pauses the download after Step 2, and the download does not finish - there are no further error messages or warnings showing up. When I bring the App to foreground the download resumes and finishes.

But when I try the same with the simulator and **ios 8.1** everything works as expected.

And now the best part:

On the **device with ios 10.2** everything works also as expected, so now the question is why not on the simulator? Could that be due to some resource restrictions applying in the simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you found a bug with the 10.2 simulator. It's not surprising. The simulator is actually written on top of OS X frameworks, with glue code to make it act like iOS.

I've found that problems seem to crop up in the parts of the simulator that interact with OSX or with the custom hardware on iOS devices.

There are various inconsistencies in the file system, and things like GPS and the acellerometer aren't fully supported.

It's not that surprising that the simulator doesn't get background NSURLSession handling quite right. Managing the download of files from outside your app and re-launching your app on completion requires interacting with low level task scheduling.

I would suggest filing a Radar bug with Apple.

Comment: Thanks Duncan C for the explanation. I would be curious if anybody experiences the same problem...